# Stuck at Ionic development

Tags: angularjs, authentication, ionic-framework

I am trying to learn Ionic programming and I would like to create an application with an Login site in which one is able to enter login/pw information and is then proceeded to a site with an side menu.

I tried to adapt this example:
https://github.com/GeorgiCodes/ionic-side-menu-with-navigation

My problem is now that I want to navigate to the Login page and afterwards to the menu site but if I try to do so it just shows a blank page to me

This is my index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Ionic Seed</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

    <!-- ionic css -->
    <link href="css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- your app's css -->
    <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- angularjs scripts -->
    <script src="js/vendor/ionic/ionic.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/angular/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/angular/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/angular/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/angular/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/ionic/ionic-angular.min.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's script -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
</head>

<!-- 'sideMenuApp' is the name of this angular module (js/app.js)-->
<body ng-app="sideMenuApp">

<ion-nav-view>
    <ion-view>
        <ion-content>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
</ion-nav-view>


</body>
</html>
```

This is the login.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<ion-view view-title="Login" name="login-view">
    <ion-content class="padding">
        <div class="list list-inset">
            <label class="item item-input">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Username" ng-model="data.username">
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="data.password">
            </label>
        </div>
        <button class="button button-block button-calm" ng-click="login()">Login</button>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

and this the menu.html

```html
<ion-view>
    <ion-content>

        <div>
            <ion-side-menus>

                <!-- Center content -->
                <ion-pane ion-side-menu-content>
                    <ion-nav-bar type="bar-assertive" back-button-type="button-icon"
                                 back-button-icon="ion-arrow-left-c"></ion-nav-bar>

                    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
                </ion-pane>

                <!-- Left Side Menu -->
                <ion-side-menu side="left">
                    <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-header bar-assertive">
                        <h1 class="title">Menu</h1>
                    </ion-header-bar>
                    <ion-content has-header="true">
                        <ion-list>
                            <ion-item ng-click="goTo(item.link)" class="item item-icon-left" ng-repeat="item in list">
                                <i ng-class="item.iconClass"></i>
                                {{item.text}}
                            </ion-item>
                        </ion-list>
                    </ion-content>
                </ion-side-menu>

            </ion-side-menus>
        </div>


    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

at last the app.js

```html
var sideMenuApp = angular.module('sideMenuApp', ['ionic', 'sideMenuApp.controllers', 'sideMenuApp.services']);

sideMenuApp.config(function ($compileProvider) {
    $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|file|tel):/);
})

sideMenuApp.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    // Ionic uses AngularUI Router which uses the concept of states
    // Learn more here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
    // Set up the various states which the app can be in.
    // Each state's controller can be found in controllers.js
    $stateProvider

        .state('login',{
            url: 'login',
            controller: 'MyLogin_Controller',
            templateUrl: 'templates/login.html'
        })
        .state('menu', {
            url: 'menu',
            controller:'Menu_Controller',
            templateURL: 'templates/menu.html'
        });

       /* .state('one', {
            url: '/one',
            controller: 'OneController',
            templateUrl: 'templates/one.html'
        })
        .state('two', {
            url: '/two',
            controller: 'TwoController',
            templateUrl: 'templates/two.html'
        })
        .state('three', {
            url: '/three',
            controller: 'ThreeController',
            templateUrl: 'templates/three.html'
        });
*/
    // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
    }
])
```

and the controller.js

```html
angular.module('sideMenuApp.controllers', [])

    .controller('MyLogin_Controller', function($scope, LoginService, $ionicPopup, $state) {
        $scope.data = {};

        $scope.login = function() {
            LoginService.loginUser($scope.data.username, $scope.data.password).success(function(data) {
                $state.go('one');
            }).error(function(data) {
                var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                    title: 'Wrong Login',
                    template: 'Please check your credentials!'
                });
            });
        }
    })

    .controller('Menu_Controller', function ($scope, $location, MenuService) {
        // "MenuService" is a service returning mock data (services.js)
        $scope.list = MenuService.all();

        $scope.goTo = function(page) {
            console.log('Going to ' + page);
            $scope.sideMenuController.toggleLeft();
            $location.url('/' + page);
        };
    })

    .controller('OneController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.navTitle = "";

        $scope.leftButtons = [{
            type: 'button-icon icon ion-navicon',
            tap: function(e) {
                $scope.sideMenuController.toggleLeft();
            }
        }];

        $scope.rightButtons = [];
    })

    .controller('TwoController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.navTitle = "";

        $scope.leftButtons = [{
            type: 'button-icon icon ion-navicon',
            tap: function(e) {
                $scope.sideMenuController.toggleLeft();
            }
        }];

        $scope.rightButtons = [];
    })

    .controller('ThreeController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.navTitle = "";

        $scope.leftButtons = [{
            type: 'button-icon icon ion-navicon',
            tap: function(e) {
                $scope.sideMenuController.toggleLeft();
            }
        }];

        $scope.rightButtons = [];
    });
```

The one,two,three.html are blank so far.

I have read so far that the One, Two, Three.html maybe have to be a child of menu so that it would be something like that

.state('menu.one', {
         url: '/one',
         controller: 'OneController',
         templateUrl: 'templates/one.html'
         })

but the problem is that I cant even reach the menu or the login page at the beginning.
I thought that normally it should at least go to the login with $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
but it is just a blank page.
I am pretty sure that there is something wrong in the index.html or the login / menu controllers but at this point I just cant figure it out so maybe one of you can give me a hint or sees the problem.

Thanks in advance and best regards

Answer (score 0):

if you do menu.one , then you need to create a child view in your menu.html

```
<ion-nav-view name="childView">  
</ion-nav-view>
```

and your state will look like

```
.state('one', {
            url: '/one',
            views:{
                  childView:{ 
                         controller: 'OneController',
                         templateUrl: 'templates/one.html'
                   }
            }

  })
```

Comment: Thank you this helps but my problem is that it doens't even show me the login or the menu view in the first place just a blank page

Comment: what does your console say ? are you developing on a device or webpage ?

Comment: console gives me no error so far
I am working on an ionic program on Webstrom 10.0.2 and testing it with a webpage.

I think that something in my index.html <body> ion view---</body> goes wrong
but normally as far as I read it should load at least the default page and not nothing.
If I put the information directly in the index.html it seems to work but as soon as it gets split up in different .html it doesnt

Comment: in your login.html , put <ion-nav-view>         </ion-nav-view>, means just wrap the entire thing in <ion-nav-view>

Comment: and remove  <ion-view>  <ion-content>   </ion-content>   </ion-view> from index.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to change yoru state URL

You defined :

```
 url: 'login',
```

and it shall be

```
 url: '/login',
```